# windows app live video

Tags: windows, activex, directx

Whats the best and easiest way to play an incoming live video stream in a c++ windows application (visual studio 2010) and write some notes (eg. this is a blue ball) on the stream display? ActiveX? DirectX? Flash?

I have Windows SDK 7.1 installed. Do I need to install any other software?

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplest, you can do everything you ask with just directshow. There is [directshow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) managed library that wraps it for you.

So - try to find an example that just gets video from capture device to the renderer.  Then, insert SampleGrabber filter in between those, and modify frame data accordingly.  I am using such technique to draw timestamp on the recorded video in my recorder, I am even drawing it with simple GDI+ calls.

Thing to consider: you'll have to watch out for PICTURE format - some webcams have YUY2 as default or ONLY format.  You'll want RGB24 format to be able to wrap `Bitmap` then `Graphics` around it.

Comment: just play the live video with some text. i might add some simple graphics as well..a circle for eg.

Comment: Here, some more explanation...  ask away what clarification is needed.